# Python "IndentationError: expected an indented block" After Checking Indentation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting the following error even though I've checked all the idents to make sure they're indents and not spaces:

File "", line 13
    """

^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

```
import random

def guess_the_number():

    number, guesses = random.randint( 1, 20 ), 1

    inpName = input('Hello! Enter your name? \n')

    print('{}, there is a number f a number between 1 and 20.'.format(inpName))
    print('Take a guess what it is.')

    guess = input()

    while guess != number:

        if guess < number:
            print('That is too low.')
            print('Take another guess.')
            guesses += 1
            guess = input()

        else:
            print('That is to high.')
            print('Take another guess.')
            guesses += 1
            guess = input()

     if guess == number:
        print('Good job {} you guessed the number in {} guesses!'.format(inpName, guesses))
```

Comment: The indentation of the final `if` statement is off.

Comment: `if guess == number:` is not aligned properly. Looks like it should be aligned outside of the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Also for your further references, it is recommended by the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) that

> Spaces are the preferred indentation method. Tabs should be used solely to remain consistent with code that is already indented with tabs.